# FusionChart not displaying the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graph, fusioncharts

I am using Fusionchart Multi-series column 3d + line with dual y axis,
I put my data in an array like this

```
mttr.push({
  :label => Date::MONTHNAMES[month],
  :value => (monthly_failure[month] / total_circuit)
})
```

and the dataset field like this

```
:dataset => [
    {
        :seriesname => 'Downtime',
        :color => 'AFD8F8',
        :showvalues => '0',
        :data => downtime
    },
    {
        :seriesname => 'MTTR',
        :color => 'F6BD0F',
        :showvalues => '0',
        :data => mttr

    },
    {
        :seriesname => 'SLA',
        :color => '8BBA00',
        :showvalues => '0',
        :parentyaxis => 'S',
        :renderas => 'Line',
        :data => sla

    }
]
```

I have tried my code and there is no problem with the data, but the graph still blank. is it becacuse i am not using the "categories" field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For implementing multi series charts you need to have categories objects as they are used to specify x axis labels for multi series charts.

Also note that FusionCharts have dedicated Ruby on Rails wrapper.

You can check the documentation from here http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-server-side-languages/ruby-on-rails/introduction.html